# Emacs doesn't show cyryllic properly over SSH

Tags: character-encoding, display

I'm using SSH to connect to remote server. On the server, I'm running emacs (`emacsclient -c`). It servers as my console, text editor and WM. While everything works nice when I'm not dealing with cyryllic, when I'm to work with cyryllic letters, it gets bad.

I have a file, let's call it `x`, with "Юра" string in it. If I `cat` the file from console(without using Emacs), I get proper output. However, if I open it in Emacs, or `cat` it from `ansi-term`, I get the following output:

> \u042E\u0440\u0430

Now that's obviously not something I want. How can I make Emacs display the cyryllic?

`locale` is the same both under `ansi-term` and the terminal Emacs's running in(the one where russina letters are displayed correctly).

Comment: What is the output of `locale`?

Comment: @Gilles - LANG=en_US.UTF-8, LANGUAGE=EN_US
Rest is set to C.

Comment: `LANGUAGE=EN_US` doesn't look right (`LANGUAGE` should be unset, it's only useful if you have multiple settings there, and even if it's set it should probably be set to `en_US.UTF8`), but I can't reproduce that behavior with these settings. Do you have the same problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -q`? Does the problem occur only with `emacsclient` or does it also occur if you run a new Emacs session? What is the version of Emacs and where was it installed from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing `LC_ALL` to `en_US.utf8`:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
```

then, I opened emacs again. Voila, I can see everything clearly now. :)